# How can I make each flush() work, which make each buffer sent before next write() in C#

Tags: c#, android, sockets, image-processing

I am trying to sent very screenshot when i move the mouse on the screen. Therefore, I will sent the size of screenshot and image byte[]. In my client side, I will set the size byte array by the size received from server, and read the rest of byte[] as image. Ideally, I need each time I call the write(), the byte[] I want write into should be empty, so I use the flush(). In fact, after I received the getinputstream(), Sometime  I will get the old data inside it. I don't know why flush() doesn't work. anyone has better ideas to solve this problem?

**This is my code for server, I try use stream, and networkstream, it dosent works.**

```
public void send(byte[] imageByte)
    {

        Stream stream = client.GetStream();
            client.NoDelay = true;
            client.Client.NoDelay = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("noDelay:{0}, client.noDelay:{1}", client.NoDelay, client.Client.NoDelay);
            byte[] imageSize;
            string imgSize = Convert.ToString(imageByte.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine("string=" + imgSize);
            imageSize = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imgSize);
            Debug.WriteLine(" header size:" + imageSize.Length);
            //ns.Write(imageSize, 0, imageSize.Length);
            //ns.Flush();
            //sleep 500 ms
            stream.Write(imageSize, 0, imageSize.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            Debug.WriteLine("sent size");
            //ns.Write(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length);
            //ns.Flush();
            stream.Write(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length);
            stream.Flush();

            Debug.WriteLine("First time sent image size:" + imageByte.Length);
```

client side:

```
public class connection extends AsyncTask {
    private byte[] data;

    public void setByteSize(int size) {
        data = new byte[size];

    }

    public byte[] getByteSize() {
        return data;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.126", 8080);
            // clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.172", 8080);
            System.out.println("client connect to server");
            input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("getinputstream");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int chunkSize = 0;
            int tempRead = 0;
            String msg = null;
            // byte[] data = null;

            byte[] tempByte = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 4];

            try {
                // read from the inputstream
                tempRead = input.read(tempByte);
                // tempbyte has x+5 byte

                System.out.println("Fist time read:" + tempRead);
                // convert x+5 byte into String

                String message = new String(tempByte, 0, tempRead);
                msg = message.substring(0, 5);
                int msgSize = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                data = new byte[msgSize];
                // for(int i =0;i<tempRead-5;i++)
                // {
                // data[i]=tempByte[i+5];
                // }
                for (int i = 0; i < msgSize; i++) {
                    data[i] = tempByte[i + 5];
                }
                // cut the header into imageMsg
                // String imageMsg = new String(tempByte, 5, tempRead - 5);
                // convert string into byte
                System.out.println("message head:" + msg);
                byteSize = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                System.out.println("ByteSize:" + byteSize);
                // convert String into byte[]

                totalBytesRead = tempRead - 5;
                System.out.println("total Byte Read=" + totalBytesRead);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // get string for the size of image

            try {

                while (totalBytesRead != getByteSize().length) {
                    System.out.println("data length:"
                            + getByteSize().length);
                    chunkSize = input.read(getByteSize(), totalBytesRead,
                            getByteSize().length - totalBytesRead);
                    System.out.println("chunkSize is " + chunkSize);

                    totalBytesRead += chunkSize;
                    // System.out.println("Total byte read "
                    // + totalBytesRead);

                }

                System.out.println("Complete reading - total read = "
                        + totalBytesRead);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            System.out.println("deco");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    System.out.println("setImage at less than 500");

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use flush. You're just trying to hack your way out of having to write the code correctly. I recommend you just write the code correctly instead: treat your stream-based connection correctly and deal with partial writes and reads in the usual way, by checking the return value of the writes and reads and issuing additional writes and reads as necessary to have all of the data written or read.

Comment: Yes, there is no different with using flush or not. I debug the program, it shows when I move the mouse very quick, sometime there is two images buffer sent together to the client, therefore I can not read the message head correctly.